# How can I capture CoreData warnings?

Tags: ios, core-data, tdd, bdd, nsvaluetransformer

I'm practising BDD. I've got an entity called `Foobar` that contains a transformable attribute called `quux`, which I've specified (using the Core Data model editor) to be a `QuuxToBazTransformer`. The point is, `QuuxToBazTransformer` doesn't exist. Core Data should fail my test and tell me I need to implement it.

Surprisingly, the test passed: my `Foobar` appears to have been stored and Core Data only tells me as a *warning*:

```
xctest[99290:303] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name
'QuuxToBazTransformer' was found for attribute 'quux' on entity 'Foobar'
```

How can I capture this warning and make it my test failure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can capture that warning. You can test the existence of the value transformer, though, by doing something like

1. Get a list of all entities from your model, using the `entitiesByName` method.
2. Find the `NSEntityDescription` for this entity in the dictionary returned in the previous step.
3. Get all of the attributes on the entity description, using `attributesByName`.
4. Get the name of the value transformer class on the attribute that uses it, using `valueTransformerName` on `NSAttributeDescription`.
5. Use `NSClassFromString` to verify the existence of the value transformer class.

If the value transformer class exists, you'll get a non-nil result in step 5.

You could also implement this as a more general check that looks for *all* value transformers to validate all of them. To do that, just iterate through every entity returned by `entitiesByName` and then through every attribute returned by `attributesByName` (instead of looking up a known entity and attribute by name). Any time you find a value transformer, check that the class exists (and, I guess, that it subclasses `NSValueTransformer`) to decide if the test should pass.